# how to let user enter number of Listview rows to be displayed

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

I am using a custom array adapter to display grades in a ListView, my question is how can I let a user set the number of rows displayed? I will take their selection in an editbox and then when they hit a button called "select" I will limit the display. I have searched for this elsewhere but couldn't find exactly how to perform this method. Thanks.

Comment: can you elaborate the need?

Answer (score 0):

Just implement this code after onClick()

```
for (int i = 0; i < userInput; i++) {
    yourList.add(data);
}

MyCustomAdapter dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(yourCkass.this.getActivity(),
                            R.yourLayoutListItem, yourList);

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```